# How do I get a div to expand with its contents?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with these properties

```
#content {
background-image: url('img/cbg.png');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
padding-bottom:50px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The background only shows up for 70px (I think) and then stops, then the rest of the stuff inside the div just goes on down the page like normal. If I set display:inline-block, it works correctly but uncenters my div.

Comment: Are you floating anything on the page? Could be a float clearing problem.

Comment: @TheDeeno Yes, I have a div to the right of the content div which floats right. Is that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have elements in the container which are floating, it's possible that the floats aren't properly being cleared. If this is your problem there are a bunch of work-arounds - they're called "clearfixs".

[One of my favorite write-ups was here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). The css they used in this example was here.

```
div.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

div.left {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

div.right {
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're doing `repeat-y` which means it'll only repeat vertically. If the background image is 70px, that would support the issue. Either use `repeat-x` or just `repeat`.

Comment: After some testing, I have concluded that the height of the background image is just from the padding.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't expand any longer because you have set your `#content` width to *960px* in your browser window.

In the case of your image expanding only up to `70px`, it is probably because that's the actual `height` of the image you've used. but mistakenly used `repeat-y` *(repeat vertically)*.

Here's a simple concept in `background-repeat`:

1. If you want to repeat the image vertically, create an image that is horizontally wide.
2. If you want to repeat the image horizontally, create an image that is vertically tall.